# removing/converting characters from db query when using fpdf to create pdf

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, fpdf

I am pulling data from an mysql table and using fpdf to create a pdf file.  I am pulling data from a field called abstr, so I have $abstract = $data['abstr'] and then $pdf->Write(5,$abstract) to write it. The problem is that the text comes out like this:

```
<p>Inferences and assumptions assist in information processing but also deny rather than facilitate critical thinking. Critical thinking is foundational to the development of tolerance and respectful relationships. Assignments in our course on &ldquo;hate&rdquo; have been shown to foster an inclusive world view, but students' lack of tolerance for ambiguity interferes with this progression.</p>
```

how do I get rid of/convert

```
<p>, </p>,&ldquo;
```

and other characters?  I have tried html_entity_decode, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `utf8_decode($abstract)`

Comment: That did it!  At least it got rid of the <p></p>.  I can go in and fix the occasional odd character myself.  Thanks!